# Mostrar imagen de SQL Server en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo una tabla en SQL Server en la cual agrego una imagen tipo varbinary(max) de la siguiente manera:

```
con.Open();
string query = "INSERT INTO TablaUser (Nombre, Edad, Correo, Imagen)
values (@Nombre, @Edad, @Correo, @Imagen)";
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", nomp.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edad", edad.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Correo", mail.Text);
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
byte[] input = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen", input);
}
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Ahora lo que necesito es recuperar esa imagen y mostrarla en un:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"/>
```

Este es mi código, no marca error pero no muestra la imagen:

```
con.Open();
string query = "SELECT Imagen FROM TablaUser where IdSolicitud=" + idSolicitud + "";
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
byte[] img = (byte[])cm.ExecuteScalar();
System.Drawing.Image rImage = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img))
{
rImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img);
}
con.Close();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen varbinary(max)

Comment: Como sabes que no marca error ? alli veo que defines un catch, pero no veo que hagas nada con el exception, deberias mostrarlo en un laber o loguearlo en un archivo. Recomendaria que quites el try...catch

Comment: tu url de imagen apunta a un recurso uri, ya sea que crees una carpeta y escribas la imagen alli y despues referenciarlo, o puedes hacer un handler del lado del servidor para que sea un recurso temporal, o una llamada a una accion <img src="/Usuario/ObtenerFoto/@imagen.ID"/>, o un javascript blob como recurso que suena a lo que quieres hacer. Pero primero debes determinar cual opcion quieres realizar

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ya lo depure y no muestra error en el catch

Comment: `rImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);` Aqui llamas a "R"image y en tu propiedad `Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img);` Conviertes a Base64 a "img"

Comment: @fredyfx asi es...

Comment: @Huntzberger estas seguro que el array de bytes es una imagen???, lo que tienes debe funcionar. Ya verificaste si en algun otro lado utilizas la propiedad ImageUrl la cual sobre-escribas lo que acabas de hacer???.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa hola, en ningún otro lado utilizo ImageUrl

Comment: Ok, y estas seguro que el array de bytes es una imagen???

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa quiero pensar que si ...

Comment: Si puedes modificar algunos de los registros y agregar una imagen en si, y pruebas con ese registro. Recordar que si es sensitiva la data que tienes siempre hacer un backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haber, el fragmento de código que tienes debe de funcionar.

Prueba validando que por lo menos el array de bytes tiene información.

```
string query = "SELECT Imagen FROM TUsers where IdSolicitud=" + idSolicitud + "";
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cm.CommandTimeout = 0;

byte[] img = (byte[])cm.ExecuteScalar();

if (img != null && img.Length > 0)
{
    Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img);
}
```

Nota:

> También te aconsejo que revises si de verdad el array de bytes que obtienes es una imagen en si, de lo contrario no mostrara nada.

---

Si sigues teniendo el problema entonces créate un proyecto a parte el cual vas a utilizar de pruebas. Agregas un control `Image` y haces lo siguiente en el Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("ruta_imagen");
    byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img);
}
```

`ruta_imagen` debes colocar la ruta de cualquier imagen que agregues al proyecto incluyendo la extensión.

Con este proyecto de pruebas que harás te debe de cargar la imagen en base 64, así saldrás de duda.

Comment: Hola probé poniendo directamente la ruta de cualquier imagen y no la carga... :o

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema es el siguiente:

Te falta adicionar el tipo de contenido que sigue al inicio de la fuente "source" de la imagen:

```
Image1.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64,"
```

claro que eso dependerá del formato que estés usando jpg, png, gif.

```
con.Open();
string query = "SELECT Imagen FROM TUsers where IdSolicitud=" + idSolicitud + "";
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
byte[] img = (byte[])cm.ExecuteScalar();
System.Drawing.Image rImage = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img))
{
rImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
Image1.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img);
}
con.Close();
```

Recuerda cambiar el tipo del contenido dependiendo de la extensión de la imagen!

Verifica que use la propiedad Src

Para probar que se visualiza correctamente prueba con un archivo físico:

```
Image1.Src = @"data:image/gif;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(@"/images/your_image.gif")));
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta pero sigue sin mostrarme la imagen

Comment: @Huntzberger revisa el contenido del archivo que tenga la misma longitud de bytes que el original, con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: si hago esto :Image1.Src = @"data:image/gif;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(@"/images/your_image.gif"))); tampoco me muestra la imagen :T

Answer (score 0):

A partir del byte array puedes cargar la imagen de esta forma sin usar MemoryStream:

```
con.Open();
string query = "SELECT Imagen FROM TUsers where IdSolicitud=" + idSolicitud + "";
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
byte[] img = (byte[])cm.ExecuteScalar();

//Carga imagen 
Image1.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img);

/*System.Drawing.Image rImage = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img))
{
rImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img);
}*/
con.Close();
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta pero sigue sin mostrarme la imagen

Comment: @Huntzberger probaste con "data:image/jpg;base64," ?

Comment: si, tambien lo probe asi y no muestra nada

Answer (score 0):

Deberías probar añadiendo **`Image1.Visible = true`**, por otro lado debes verificar que realmente sea una imagen lo que tienes en base de datos

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img);
Image1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] img = (byte[])reader[11];

if (img != null && img.Length > 0)
{
   Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img);
}
```

*/ corrí un select con la información que requería, y en mi form agregué el objeto de una imagen1  despues declare la variable img y le dí el valor donde tenia almacenada la imagen.

Espero te sirva/*

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenía el mismo problema de que no mostraba la imagen, pero mi campo Sql era tipo *image*, y en mi caso tenía la siguiente función en la capa datos

```
public String LeeFoto(int idSolicitud)
{
    con.Open();
    string query = "SELECT Imagen FROM TUsers where IdSolicitud=" + idSolicitud + "";
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
    return cm.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

La solución fue cambiar string por var: public var LeeFoto...
`byte[] img = LeeFoto(id) Image1.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img);`.

Espero que le sirva a alguien.