# Mostrar imagen en tabla

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tengo una tabla donde tengo la información de Clientes.

Recientemente añadí otro campo para el logo de dicho clientes, ya pude guardar la imagen en una tabla de `sql server` como tipo de dato `varchar`, pero ahora el problema es que no se como mostrar esa imagen en la tabla.

He estado intentándolo pero no me da

```
<tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr role="row" class="odd" tabindex="0">

                                    <td>
                                        @item.Nombre
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.RazonSocial
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.Sector
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.Poliza.Descripcion
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.Rfc
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", @item.FechaInicioPoliza)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Aquí va el logo
                                        @{
                                            if (item.Logo != null)
                                            {
                                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Logo))
                                                {
                                                    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(item.Logo);
                                                    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                                                    string imgSrc = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", base64);
                                                    <img src="@imgSrc" />
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <span>SIN LOGO</span>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y porque no guardas solo la ruta en la DB y subes a una carpeta el logo, luego lo llamas con el **src** del **img**?? Esa es la mejor practica.

Por otro lado puedes usar

```
string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Foto);
string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
<img src="@imageSrc" />
```

Y revisar [este topic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/259739/mostrar-imagen-de-sql-server-en-asp-net)

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia.